# Measure Time Taken By A Function And Don'T Understand Why Time Difference is Negative

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datetime, time

I am trying to check how much time does a function takes to execute in my code :

I did this :

```
void foo()
{

int time = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

// code of my function. do this, that, etc.

Console.WriteLine((System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond-time).ToString());

}
```

What i get is this :

```
-247
```

I don't understand why minus ??
& please tell me ways to measure time taken by a function.
& If pro-filer is an option then please recommend me some simple option.

Note : Here I have shown a console app but in practice i need for a Web App in ASP.NET which may be n-tier architecture also.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[DateTime.Millisecond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx) returns the millisecond part of the current date/time, not the milliseconds since some previous date/time.

Use a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// ...

Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning Stopwatch and explaining why it didn't work their way

Comment: So, What can be done to check time taken by a function in a Simple Way.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using and subtracting the *current millisecond*

e.g.

- 2010-01-01 00:00:00:999 -> System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond is 999
- 2010-01-01 00:00:01:000 -> System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond is 000

000 - 999 = -999; not terribly useful!

Using DateTime.Now to profile isn't recommended anyway. If you're just trying to get an idea, you probably want to look at [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):-

```
void Foo()
{
  Stopwatch myStopWatch = StopWatch.StartNew()

  // Your code goes here;

  Console.WriteLine(myStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

For "real world" use, though, [you're best using a profiler.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Millisecond` returns the millisecond component of the current time.
In other words, it returns the total number of milliseconds mod 1,000.
For example, if you happen to get the property at the exact end of a second, it will be 0.

Instead, you should use the `Stopwatch` class.

Answer (score 1):

The [Millisecond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx) property returns the milliseconds *component* of the date, i.e. a number between `0` and `999`.

As others have said, you can use the [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class, or you can call the [DateTime.Subtract()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) method to obtain a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instance, then use the [TotalMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) property of that instance to get the total elapsed milliseconds between your two times:

```
public void Foo()
{
    DateTime then = DateTime.Now;
    // ...
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(then).TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).